PYasn1 decoding through sequence only decodes part of the data
I am decoding a der file into asn1 structure. However when using my self defined asn1 structure in pyasn1, I am getting errors decoding a byte array.
So I tried to use:
decoded_data, remainder = asn1_decode.decode(data, univ.sequence()
However this will only decode part of the data. But when I put this same data into cyber chef, parse asn1 hex string it will show the whole data.
Is there a way to decode through univ.sequence() to decode all the data.
